# spctl "command not found" on Recovery start (mac OS Big Sierra)

Tags: terminal, command-line, recovery, firewall

I've just updated to macOS Big Sur.
The firewall I use, Little Snitch doesn't work with Big Sur natively, and you have to do some stuff (they explain the thing here https://obdev.at/support/littlesnitch/245913651253917):

1. Start up your computer from macOS Recovery: Restart your computer and hold Command-R during startup.
2. Open the Terminal application from the Utilities menu in the menu bar.
3. Enter the following command and press Return:
   *spctl kext-consent add MLZF7K7B5R*

My mac starts on Internet Recovery Mode and everytime I run the command I get the result "*command not found*"
I tried to look for the command in the route /usr/sbin/ but neither found there.
[image: I also image description here]
Any idea of what can i do to run it?

Thanks in advance and regards :)

Comment: I do believe that V5 (recently released) Does natively support Big Sur. Is that an option for you?

Comment: Thanks Steve, my Little Snitch license is just for v4, i would preffer not to update (and pay) for v5 if I can run 4 on Big Sur.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have booted into an older version of macOS Recovery (there's an item called "Install OS X Yosemite.app" visible in your screenshot). This is something that can happen with Internet Recovery, depending on the Mac model and OS version.

If you use the regular local Recovery (<kbd>⌘ R</kbd>), the `spctl` command should be available.

If you HAVE to use Internet Recovery, try <kbd>⌥ ⌘ R</kbd>. This should load the latest version of macOS compatible with your Mac.